# I have a 1999 Suzuki marauder and need codes

Tags: troubleshooting, engine-load, preventive-maintenance, seized-engine, servicing

How do I pull service codes from my 1999 Suzuki marauder v800?

Comment: Do you have a compatible code reader? If not, can you borrow one? Or some stores will have them for loan, or you could purchase one.

Comment: I can borrow one